# onclick events not triggering when dynamically created buttons are re-created

Tags: javascript

I'm dynamically creating buttons on the page using an array that's populated via table cells content inside separating columns. The buttons filter the table rows by matching the innerHTML of the anchor to the cell content innerHTML, this is happening inside a function. Once this filter is applied I have a function that  removes and rebuilds the buttons so I can visually reflect the table rows and button options being filtered.

My issue is that once the buttons have done their job, filtered the table rows and being removed and re-built, the onclick and additional table filtering is no longer triggering. I have a hunch that maybe the button array needs to be cleared and allowed to be rebuilt but having tried that still I'm getting nothing.

```
var hash = window.location.hash.split('+');
/*var sector = hash[0].substring(1);
var service = hash[1];
var client = hash[2];*/
var titleInput = document.getElementById("docSearch");
var docTable = document.getElementById("matrix").getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var docTableRows = docTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var URLpath = window.location.pathname;
var typeContainer = document.getElementById("typeButtons");
var sectorContainer = document.getElementById("sectorButtons");
var serviceContainer = document.getElementById("serviceButtons");
var clientContainer = document.getElementById("clientButtons");
var typeArray =  new Array();
var sectorArray = new Array();
var serviceArray = new Array();
var clientArray = new Array();
var savedTypeTableRows = new Array();
var savedSectorTableRows = new Array();
var savedServiceTableRows = new Array();
var savedClientTableRows = new Array();

/*--------PAGE FUNCTIONS--------*/
function resetPage() {
  window.location = URLpath;
}

/*--------BUTTON FUNCTIONS--------*/

/*----RESET ARRAYS----*/
function resetArrays(){
  typeArray = [];
  sectorArray = [];
  serviceArray = [];
  clientArray = [];  
  savedTypeTableRows = [];
  savedSectorTableRows = [];
  savedServiceTableRows = [];
  savedClientTableRows = [];
}

function resetButtons(){
  resetTypeButtons();
  resetSectorButtons();
  resetServiceButtons();
  resetClientButtons();
}

function createButtons(){
  createTypeButtons();
  createSectorButtons();
  createServiceButtons();
  createClientButtons();
}

/*----TYPE BUTTON CREATION----*/
 function createTypeButtons(){
  for ( var i = 1; i < docTable.rows.length; i++ ) {
    typeArrayCount = docTable.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
    typeArray.push(typeArrayCount); 
  }
  var uniqueTypes = typeArray.filter(function(elem, index, self) {return index == self.indexOf(elem);});
  console.log(uniqueTypes);
  var typeLength = uniqueTypes.length;
  var typeButton;
  for (i = 0; i < typeLength; i++) {
    typeButton = document.createElement('a');
    typeButton.className = 'button cyan filterButton';
    typeButton.innerHTML = uniqueTypes[i];
    typeButton.style.marginRight = "5px";
    typeButton.href = "#" + uniqueTypes[i].replace(" ","%20");
    typeContainer.appendChild(typeButton);
  }
}

/*----BUILD TYPE BUTTONS----*/
createTypeButtons();

/*----CLEAR THE TYPE BUTTONS AND REBUILD----*/
function resetTypeButtons(){
  while (typeContainer.hasChildNodes()) {
    typeContainer.removeChild(typeContainer.lastChild);
  }
  createTypeButtons();
}

/*----FILTER THE TABLE BASED ON TYPE----*/
function typeFilterTable(){
  var typeFilter, typeColumn, i; 
  typeFilter = this.hash.substring(1).toUpperCase(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < docTableRows.length; i++) {
    savedTypeTableRows.push(docTableRows[i]);
  }
  savedTypeTableRows.forEach(function(row){
      var typeColumn = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
       if (typeColumn) {
         var contents = typeColumn.innerHTML.toUpperCase().replace(" ","%20");
         if (contents.indexOf(typeFilter) > -1) {
         /*do nothing*/
         }else{
         row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
         resetArrays();
         resetButtons();
         }
       }
  });   
}

/*----SECTOR BUTTON CREATION----*/
function createSectorButtons(){
  for ( var i = 1; i < docTable.rows.length; i++ ) {
    sectorArrayCount = docTable.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
    sectorArray.push(sectorArrayCount);
  }
  var uniqueSectors = sectorArray.filter(function(elem, index, self) { return index == self.indexOf(elem); });
  console.log(uniqueSectors);
  var sectorLength = uniqueSectors.length;
  var sectorButton;
  for (i = 0; i < sectorLength; i++) {
    sectorButton = document.createElement('a');
    sectorButton.className = 'button cyan filterButton';
    sectorButton.innerHTML = uniqueSectors[i];
    sectorButton.style.marginRight = "5px";
    sectorButton.href = "#" + uniqueSectors[i].replace(" ","%20");
    sectorContainer.appendChild(sectorButton);
  }
}

/*----BUILD SECTOR BUTTONS----*/
createSectorButtons();

/*----CLEAR THE SECTOR BUTTONS AND REBUILD----*/
function resetSectorButtons(){
  while (sectorContainer.hasChildNodes()) {
    sectorContainer.removeChild(sectorContainer.lastChild);
  }
  createSectorButtons();
}

/*----FILTER THE TABLE BASED ON SECTOR----*/
function sectorFilterTable(){
  var sectorFilter, sectorColumn, i; 
  sectorFilter = this.hash.substring(1).toUpperCase();

  for (var i = 0; i < docTableRows.length; i++) {
    savedSectorTableRows.push(docTableRows[i]);
  }
  savedSectorTableRows.forEach(function(row){
      var sectorColumn = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[2];
       if (sectorColumn) {
         var contents = sectorColumn.innerHTML.toUpperCase().replace(" ","%20");
         if (contents.indexOf(sectorFilter) > -1) {
         /*do nothing*/
         }else{
         row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
         resetArrays();
         resetButtons();
         }
       }
  });   
}

/*----SERVICE BUTTON CREATION----*/
 function createServiceButtons(){
  for ( var i = 1; i < docTable.rows.length; i++ ) {
    serviceArrayCount = docTable.rows[i].cells[3].innerHTML;
    serviceArray.push(serviceArrayCount); 
  }
  var uniqueServices = serviceArray.filter(function(elem, index, self) {return index == self.indexOf(elem);});
  console.log(uniqueServices);
  var serviceLength = uniqueServices.length;
  var serviceButton;
  for (i = 0; i < serviceLength; i++) {
    serviceButton = document.createElement('a');
    serviceButton.className = 'button cyan filterButton';
    serviceButton.innerHTML = uniqueServices[i];
    serviceButton.style.marginRight = "5px";
    serviceButton.href = "#" + uniqueServices[i].replace(" ","%20");
    serviceContainer.appendChild(serviceButton);
  }
}

/*----BUILD SERVICE BUTTONS----*/
createServiceButtons();

/*----CLEAR THE SERVICE BUTTONS AND REBUILD----*/
function resetServiceButtons(){
  while (serviceContainer.hasChildNodes()) {
    serviceContainer.removeChild(serviceContainer.lastChild);
  }
  createServiceButtons();
}

/*----FILTER THE TABLE BASED ON SERVICE----*/
function serviceFilterTable(){
  var serviceFilter, serviceColumn, i; 
  serviceFilter = this.hash.substring(1).toUpperCase(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < docTableRows.length; i++) {
    savedServiceTableRows.push(docTableRows[i]);
  }
  savedServiceTableRows.forEach(function(row){
      var serviceColumn = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
       if (serviceColumn) {
         var contents = serviceColumn.innerHTML.toUpperCase().replace(" ","%20");
         if (contents.indexOf(serviceFilter) > -1) {
         /*do nothing*/
         }else{
         row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
         resetArrays();
         resetButtons();
         }
       }
  });   
}

/*----CLIENT BUTTON CREATION----*/
 function createClientButtons(){
  for ( var i = 1; i < docTable.rows.length; i++ ) {
    clientArrayCount = docTable.rows[i].cells[4].innerHTML;
    clientArray.push(clientArrayCount); 
  }
  var uniqueClients = clientArray.filter(function(elem, index, self) {return index == self.indexOf(elem);});
  console.log(uniqueClients);
  var clientLength = uniqueClients.length;
  var clientButton;
  for (i = 0; i < clientLength; i++) {
    clientButton = document.createElement('a');
    clientButton.className = 'button cyan filterButton';
    clientButton.innerHTML = uniqueClients[i];
    clientButton.style.marginRight = "5px";
    clientButton.href = "#" + uniqueClients[i].replace(" ","%20");
    clientContainer.appendChild(clientButton);
  }
}

/*----BUILD CLIENT BUTTONS----*/
createClientButtons();

/*----CLEAR THE CLIENT BUTTONS AND REBUILD----*/
function resetClientButtons(){
  while (clientContainer.hasChildNodes()) {
    clientContainer.removeChild(clientContainer.lastChild);
  }
  createClientButtons();
}

/*----FILTER THE TABLE BASED ON CLIENT----*/
function clientFilterTable(){
  var clientFilter, clientColumn, i; 
  clientFilter = this.hash.substring(1).toUpperCase(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < docTableRows.length; i++) {
    savedClientTableRows.push(docTableRows[i]);
  }
  savedClientTableRows.forEach(function(row){
      var clientColumn = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[4];
       if (clientColumn) {
         var contents = clientColumn.innerHTML.toUpperCase().replace(" ","%20");
         if (contents.indexOf(clientFilter) > -1) {
         /*do nothing*/
         }else{
         row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
         resetArrays();
         resetButtons();
         }
       }
  });   
}


/*----TYPE BUTTON CLICK DETECT----*/
var allTypeFilterButtons = typeContainer.getElementsByClassName("filterButton");
for (i = 0; i < allTypeFilterButtons.length; i++) {
  typeFilterButtons = allTypeFilterButtons[i];
  typeFilterButtons.addEventListener('click', typeFilterTable);
}

/*----SECTOR BUTTON CLICK DETECT----*/
var allSectorFilterButtons = sectorContainer.getElementsByClassName("filterButton");
for (i = 0; i < allSectorFilterButtons.length; i++) {
  sectorFilterButtons = allSectorFilterButtons[i];
  sectorFilterButtons.addEventListener('click', sectorFilterTable);
}

/*----SERVICE BUTTON CLICK DETECT----*/
var allServiceFilterButtons = serviceContainer.getElementsByClassName("filterButton");
for (i = 0; i < allServiceFilterButtons.length; i++) {
  serviceFilterButtons = allServiceFilterButtons[i];
  serviceFilterButtons.addEventListener('click', serviceFilterTable);
}

/*----CLIENT BUTTON CLICK DETECT----*/
var allClientFilterButtons = clientContainer.getElementsByClassName("filterButton");
for (i = 0; i < allClientFilterButtons.length; i++) {
  clientFilterButtons = allClientFilterButtons[i];
  clientFilterButtons.addEventListener('click', clientFilterTable);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sideburnt/t9rrevto/

Comment: Stupid question - are you reapplying the addEventListener whenever you recreate the buttons?

Comment: @amadan It doesn't look like it. The event listeners are only added on startup. There is also a crazy amount of duplication in that code, I would suggest some serious refactoring. Plus, any reason why you can't use JQuery?